# Fighting Spam in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

What are the most effective and/or easiest to implement methods for reducing spam entries on a comment form in Laravel?

I have tried https://github.com/msurguy/Honeypot, but the time field doesn't pass validation I think it is because I'm using ardent?

Comment: The project you link has references off to Laravel packages for Akismet and reCaptcha, by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these packages have been updated for Laravel 4.2

Comment: Chances are they'll work and just need a `composer.json` version bump.

Comment: I usually add a hidden field with no value in the input. I then validate that input and if it contains a value it fails validation and I redirect appropriately with an appropriate error message.

Comment: @Gaz I find that method intriguing for its simplicity. Your essentially doing the same thing as in the Honeypot package mentioned in my question, minus the encrypted time field which allows for requiring the user to be on the page a certain amount of time before submitting a form. How much success have you had with this simple hoenypot field method? Any spam getting through? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jeremy Plack Not had any spam whatsoever in nearly 2 years. So seems to work well. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We implement this method at work and it stops almost all spam. You need to hide a text field (Using css "display:none" on a parent element. Don't use a hidden field, spambots know better) and when you validate the form, make sure that field has no content. If there is content, you know it is spam. Spam bots like to fill in as many fields as possible. Here is an example:

```css
.special-field {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-field">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
  <input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" value="" />
</div>
```

Applying a name to the field may help to confuse spam bots as well, further encouraging them to fill in a value.